# Knapsack solution with Backtraking in c++

Tags: c++, backtracking, knapsack-problem

Im having troubles trying to resolve the Knapsack problem using backtraking.

For example, for the following values, the Knapsack function will return 14 as the solution, but the correct result should be 7.

```
int n = 3, weights[] = {2, 3, 1}, values[] = {6, 15, 7};

int solution = 0, max = 2;


void Knapsack (int i, int max, int value, int *solution)
{
  int k;

  for (k = i; k < n; k++) {
    if (weights[k] <= max) {
      Knapsack (k, max - weights[k], value + values[k], solution);

      if (value+ values[k] > *solution) 
         *solution= value + values[k];
    }
  }
}
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: Have you tried using a really minimal problem (i.e. smaller `values[]`) and stepping through the code until you see it go wrong, then thinking about why?  Alternatively, put some `std::cout << ...` lines into your loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

int weights[] = {2, 3, 1}, values[] = {6, 15, 7};

int solution = 0, n = 3;

std::vector<int> vsol;
std::vector<int> temp;

bool issol;


void Knapsack (int i, int max, int value)
{
  for (int k = i; k < n; k++) {
    if ( max > 0)
    {
        if (weights[k] <= max)
        {
          temp.push_back(k);
          if (value+ values[k] >= solution)
          {
            solution = value + values[k];
            issol = true;
          }
        }
        if ( (k+1) < n)
        {
          Knapsack (k+1, max - weights[k], value + values[k]);
        }
        else
        {
          if (issol == true)
          {
            if (! vsol.empty()) vsol.clear();
            std::move(temp.begin(), temp.end(), std::back_inserter(vsol));
            temp.clear();
            issol = false;
          } else temp.clear();
          return;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (issol == true)
        {
            if (! vsol.empty()) vsol.clear();
            std::move(temp.begin(), temp.end(), std::back_inserter(vsol));
            temp.clear();
            issol = false;
        } else temp.clear();
        return;
    }
  }
}

int main()
{
    Knapsack(0, 2, 0);
    cout << "solution: " << solution << endl;
    for(vector<int>::iterator it = vsol.begin(); it != vsol.end(); it++)
        cout << *it << " ";
    return 0;
}
```

You need to increase k by 1 when you call the Knapsack function again to move the index forward.

Added code to print out index locations of the solution. If more than one solution exists (i.e. same total), will only print out the locations for the last solution.

Comment: Would be easy in this case to save the elements of the solution?

Comment: Sure can, you can use a container (array or whatever, preferably an STL container) to store the index positions of weights array (and values accordingly)

Comment: The right place to do that is before the recursive call?

Comment: If you don't need to do recursion, then I suggest change the knapsack into a combination of loops, which will make identifying index positions of the final result much easier.