# backtracking knapsack implementation with C++

Tags: c++, backtracking, knapsack-problem

I am trying to implement backtracking knapsack solution with C++ which was from this website. But I get error at line std::move part, that says that std does not support move. Is there a solution for that? Is that because of my development environment?

```
 if (issol == true)
        {
            if (! vsol.empty()) vsol.clear();
            std::move(temp.begin(), temp.end(), std::back_inserter(vsol));
            temp.clear();
            issol = false;
        } else temp.clear();
        return;
```

Comment: Did you include <utility> ?

Comment: You actually have to include the `<algorithm>` header, not `<utility>`.

Comment: Yes I included both <utility> and <algorithm> but it did not work. I get the error [Error] 'move' is not a member of 'std'  @0x499602D2

Answer (score 0):

`std::move` is a new feature starting from C++11 which requires including `<utility>` header file. So, check if you have #included this header file. Also, if you do not find this file then probably your development environment does not support C++11.

Reference:
[std::move](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move)

Answer (score 0):

Just include utility

```
#include <utility>
```

Comment: I tried but I still get the error [Error] 'move' is not a member of 'std'

Comment: I added here, (the second one) I get this solution from this website: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24255082/knapsack-solution-with-backtraking-in-c

Comment: I tried to compile but error did not change. Is there a solution for my development environment to compile? @Ahmed Gamal.