# Is there a solution instead of move for knapsack backtracking algorithm in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, c++builder, backtracking, knapsack-problem

I used the solution of Backtracking of Knapsack solution with C++. I had the solution again from here. [Knapsack solution with Backtraking in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24255082/knapsack-solution-with-backtraking-in-c)
My compiler gives error at line move. Is there solution without using move? how can I modify the code without using the move?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

int weights[] = {2, 3, 1}, values[] = {6, 15, 7};

int solution = 0, n = 3;

std::vector<int> vsol;
std::vector<int> temp;

bool issol;


void Knapsack (int i, int max, int value)
{
  for (int k = i; k < n; k++) {
    if ( max > 0)
    {
        if (weights[k] <= max)
        {
          temp.push_back(k);
          if (value+ values[k] >= solution)
          {
            solution = value + values[k];
            issol = true;
          }
        }
        if ( (k+1) < n)
        {
          Knapsack (k+1, max - weights[k], value + values[k]);
        }
        else
        {
          if (issol == true)
          {
            if (! vsol.empty()) vsol.clear();
            std::move(temp.begin(), temp.end(), std::back_inserter(vsol));
            temp.clear();
            issol = false;
          } else temp.clear();
          return;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (issol == true)
        {
            if (! vsol.empty()) vsol.clear();
            std::move(temp.begin(), temp.end(), std::back_inserter(vsol));
            temp.clear();
            issol = false;
        } else temp.clear();
        return;
    }
  }
}

int main()
{
    Knapsack(0, 2, 0);
    cout << "solution: " << solution << endl;
    for(vector<int>::iterator it = vsol.begin(); it != vsol.end(); it++)
        cout << *it << " ";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you include `<algorithm>`? Did you enable C++11 mode in your compiler?

Comment: Yes I also tried utility too but made no difference.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] (if you want to get that `move` working, mainly).

Comment: I edited my question. I tried to explain more clear. I hope it is ok now. @ Baum mit Augen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change [`std::move`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move) with [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy). In general they aren't equivalent, but here you are working with a vector of `int` (so there isn't a a performance penalty) and the source array is immediately cleared (`temp.clear()`).

So you can write:

```
if (!vsol.empty()) vsol.clear();
std::copy(temp.begin(), temp.end(), std::back_inserter(vsol));
```

Indeed that is over-thought. The simple:

```
vsol = temp;
```

is clear, fast and works with C++98 also (depending on your C++Builder version, C++11-compatibility could be an issue).

The modified version:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int weights[] = {2, 3, 1}, values[] = {6, 15, 7};

int solution = 0, n = 3;

std::vector<int> vsol;
std::vector<int> temp;

bool issol;

void Knapsack(int i, int max, int value)
{
  for (int k = i; k < n; ++k)
  {
    if (max > 0)
    {
      if (weights[k] <= max)
      {
        temp.push_back(k);
        if (value + values[k] >= solution)
        {
          solution = value + values[k];
          issol = true;
        }
      }

      if (k + 1 < n)
      {
        Knapsack(k + 1, max - weights[k], value + values[k]);
      }
      else
      {
        if (issol)
        {
          vsol = temp;
          issol = false;
        }

        temp.clear();
        return;
      }
    }
    else
    {
      if (issol)
      {
        vsol = temp;
        issol = false;
      }

      temp.clear();
      return;
    }
  }
}

int main()
{
  Knapsack(0, 2, 0);
  std::cout << "solution: " << solution << '\n';
  for(std::vector<int>::iterator it = vsol.begin(); it != vsol.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << *it << " ";

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @xxxx If it solves your problem, please accept the answer. :)